# Dynamically updating html based on viewmodel

Tags: forms, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel

I'm currently trying to update some HTML based on two properties in my viewmodel which are hooked to two form groups. This is ASP.NET Core.

The two form groups:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label asp-for="ParticipantAmount">Antal deltagere</label>
   <input asp-for="ParticipantAmount" onchange="Group()" class="form-control" type="number" max="1000" min="1" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label asp-for="GroupAmount">Antal grupper</label>
   <input asp-for="GroupAmount" class="form-control" onchange="Group()" type="number" max="20" min="1" />
   <p id="GroupSize">0</p>
</div>
```

The properties in the viewmodel:

```
public int ParticipantAmount { get; set; }
public int GroupAmount { get; set; }
```

The javascript method in the script section:

```
function Group() {
    var groups = Number('@Model.GroupAmount');
    var participants = Number('@Model.ParticipantAmount');
    var size = participants / groups;
    document.getElementById('GroupSize').innerHTML = size;
}
```

When I try to log stuff to the console, it seems like the properties are not being updated in the viewmodel when the form inputs change.

I think I'm missing some basic knowledge about an important aspect of what I'm trying to do, but I can't seem to google the correct keywords. Hope you can lead me in the right direction.

Comment: In your case try googling for `AJAX` -- you need to make an `AJAX` call to your web application's back-end to update `ParticipantAmount` and `GroupAmount`.
Or better google for modern JavaScript frameworks like Angular, Knockout etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to illustrate how `AJAX` calls work I made a minimalistic web application using `jQuery` which should be used for learning only, the code is not production-ready.

Razor view. I've added default values and IDs to your the input fields to identify them easier in JavaScript code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ParticipantAmount">Antal deltagere</label>
    <input asp-for="ParticipantAmount" onchange="Group()" class="form-control" type="number" max="1000" min="1" value="@Model.ParticipantAmount" id="ParticipantAmount" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="GroupAmount">Antal grupper</label>
    <input asp-for="GroupAmount" class="form-control" onchange="Group()" type="number" max="20" min="1" value="@Model.GroupAmount" id="GroupAmount" />
    <p id="GroupSize">0</p>`enter code here`
</div>
```

JavaScript code using jQuery to get/update values and make `AJAX` request.

```
<script>
function Group() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/Home/UpdateAmounts",
        data: { ParticipantAmount: $('#ParticipantAmount').val(), GroupAmount: $('#GroupAmount').val() }
    }).done(function (response) {
        $('#GroupSize').html(response);
    });
}
</script>
```

Controller and view model. Added a method for `AJAX` calls.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new ParticipantViewModel());
    }

    // You can call this method via AJAX to update your view model
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UpdateAmounts(int participantAmount, int groupAmount)
    {
        // Validation for negative numbers, and groupAmount cannot be zero
        if (participantAmount < 0 || groupAmount <= 0)
        {
            return Ok(0);
        }

        return Ok(participantAmount / groupAmount);
    }
}

public class ParticipantViewModel
{
    public int ParticipantAmount { get; set; }

    public int GroupAmount { get; set; }
}
```

To make things nicer and more modern you could look into [following example](https://github.com/ignas-sakalauskas/NetCoreEfCoreKnockoutRequireJs) of a simple web application using database to store data, and using Knockout for UI.

Comment: Thanks!
This for sure explains what I was trying to achieve. I ended up using [Vue](https://vuejs.org/), though - what I was lacking was the knowledge about how to dynamically manipulate the elements. Cheers.